# Determine if connection is from an actual user

Tags: php, api, browser, mantis

I wrote a plugin that would execute every time a user accesses mantis bug tracker (3rd party software). Essentially, the user must go to a landing page and agree to my terms before they can access any applications, including mantis. The problem is that I am also using their api (mantis connect) to add issues/attachments to the system. My plugin is causing an issue where mantis connect is not able to complete the connection (it is executing the redirect function).

Is there a way that I can make an exception to my code so that mantis connect is ignored?

```
    function hooks() {
        return array(
       'EVENT_PLUGIN_INIT' => 'runCheck',
        );
    }

    //Main function which
    function runCheck($p_event){
        if (!$this->validSession())
            $this->redirectUser();
    }
```

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
if (!$this->validSession() && !mantisConnect())
```

I just need to know how to determine if the connection is from a mantis connect statement. The mantis connect is an API call. So maybe an option would be to detect if the user is using a browser vs a call from a script, and only execute the redirect in that case. Also the code above is written in PHP.

Alternatively, if someone knows of an alternative event hook I could use that would only execute if a mantis page is loaded, that may solve my problem as well.

Comment: Log `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to see how Connect is identifying itself, then build an exception for it.

Comment: Thanks, took time to figure what $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] had stored as I had to write the output to a file to see it, but that did resolve my issue.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said to log it - there's no predicting what a custom script is identifying itself as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know. Here is the code that I ended up using to make this work.

```
function runCheck($p_event){
   if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'PHP-SOAP') !== false){ //check for mantis connect
      if (!$this->validSession()){ //check if session is valid
         $this->redirectUser();
      }
   }
}
```